# How to redirect to specific port from DNS

Tags: dns, redirection, teamspeak

I've got a teamspeak 3 server from my friend, but problem is we've got to remember the IP address if we want to connect onto it from anywhere else than home.

So I bought domain and I wanted to redirect it to my teamspeak server. 
But the problem is:

Everytime I want to connect to my teamspeak I have to enter Port (in my case 8020) too, and I can't enter port into DNS.

Is there any way to redirect to my teamspeak server without playing with main server? I've tried some things with SRV records but couldn't get it to work.

[Here](http://www.sourcepod.com/ezwswt10-40213)  are my DNS records if it helps.

Thanks for each response.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems to me your DNS records follow the official guidelines https://support.teamspeakusa.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/293/12/does-teamspeak-3-support-dns-srv-records.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are not entered in dns. This is not possible. (It is possible some software like teamviewer can get the portnumber from srv or txt records)

In you case toust-ts3.eu points with 46.28.105.2.
So you can now replace the ip with the domain name. 
To connect with the port number attached you can just do: domain:port. (in your case: toust-ts3.eu:8020 ).

If you can enter the port on a different location in your teamviewer server setup screen (I never used it) you can just enter the domain (toust-ts3.eu) in the server location field and 8020 in the port field.

If this doesn't work it is possible that your dns server is still caching the dns records from before. (if there where any). You could try to change your hostfile for testing then.

Comment: [Here](https://support.teamspeakusa.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/293/12/does-teamspeak-3-support-dns-srv-records) it says teamspeak can read from SRV records so i wastrying to make it work like this. Before i tried to redirect it to main ip adress and in TS i tried to toust-ts3.eu:8020 which didn't work, wonder why.

Comment: Just to confirm: It does work with 46.28.105.2:8020 ? Or how do you connect now over ip?

Comment: The 46.28.105.2 was there before, when i deleted it client couldnt resolve hostname. This is my IP right now: 31.31.76.240:8020

Comment: Can you try (in a terminal or command prompt) to do:
ping toust-ts3.eu . can you tell us what ip answers you

Comment: Reply from 46.28.105.2

Comment: That is whats wrong. The ip in the a record is not the ip your server is running on. You need to change the a record to the current ip and it will work.

Comment: but in the A record i cant submit port on which server is running

Comment: You do not need to provide that. As I mentioned in my answer this is impossible. The srv record will do that with teamspeak according to the link provided by abstraks. If you correct the ip in the a record the problem will be solved.

Comment: I think i did it right but it still does not work, [Here](http://www.sourcepod.com/aydrqd53-40476) is how i set it up this time, please, tell me whats wrong.

Comment: Ok, so i resolved issue by myself after try and check technique while looking at teamspeak3 logs which led me to victory :). [These](http://www.sourcepod.com/axbebl69-40674) are my current DNS records and its all working! Thank you for all your help!